# How to make my WooCommerce products loop open a popup instead of single product site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, popup, elementor

I'm making a food ordering website with WooCommerce and Elementor Pro. I need that Select options button or See the product button open a popup (like quick view) instead of product page. With the same content of course, so that you can choose the options and add item to cart from this popup. So that it would be functioning similar to Wolt (example: https://wolt.com/sl/svn/koper/restaurant/mcdonalds-koper).

Does anyone know a solution? Thank you.

I tried Shop Engine plugin for making a Quick view popup, but does not work with displaying products with Elementor Loop grid.

Comment: There are many Quick View plugins paid and free. You will need to do changes anyway to hide your product button and links from the product template.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript/jQuery to handle the click event on the "**Select options**" or "**See the product**" button.

Create a popup structure (HTML) that mirrors the product details and options. Then, use jQuery to show this popup when the button is clicked, and load the product content dynamically using AJAX if needed. Then, you can customize the appearance and behavior of the popup using CSS.